# Any solution to reduce the tolerance of a potentiometer?

Tags: potentiometer, tolerance

[image]

In my design we use a slider potentiometer value of 10k with tolerance of 20%.

At particular point of potentiometer whenever I come to that position my resistance value changes every time. Also every time I change the limit of the potentiometer like 10k resistor it sometimes goes to 11k and sometimes goes only 8k.

Please give the any idea or suggest me any good potentiometer to purchase.
or something like any circuit to reduce the tolerance.
[datasheet of potentiometer](https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/pta.pdf).

1. *ress ic 12* is connected to MCU pin.
2. I measure the resistance across the potentiometer 2 pins.
3. This pot is linear.
4. I stop at particular place and mark there with pen after I move and stop there place and take reading of resistance.

Comment: You're using the potentiometer as a resistor with two pins? Not a voltage divider with 3 pins? What is the circuit it is being used in? And is the repeatability of angular position and resistance actually important? (Important for something like monitoring angular position of a servo shaft, not important for something like volume control where a person just adjusts and uses sensors/senses until they get what they want). Because for many applications like the servo motor you would wire the pot as a divider, not as a variable resistor,  and the problem would go away.

Comment: Use a precision potentiometer. Nevertheless it does sound suspicious that you’re not getting repeatable results even with a average pot. Maybe the problem is elsewhere?

Comment: i am using the potentiometer as a resistor.

Comment: You might just have a crappy pot. A plastic potentiometer has low stiction and so will better read the same resistance while sliding and when stopping at a position...as long as the temperature is the same because conductive plastic has poor temperature stability. A cermet potentiometer as good temperature stability but more stiction.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic. The rest of your question requires you to provide more information (what is the circuit you are making) before we can give you a useful answer.

Comment: please see the attach image

Comment: That circuit is not using the pot as resistor. That circuit is using the pot as voltage divider.

Comment: ok but as i slide the potentiometer so why resistance is change frequent at same position?

Comment: 1. Please [edit] to tell us what is connected to "ress ic 12". 2. How did you measure the resistance? 3. Is the pot linear or log (audio taper). 4. How do you know you are moving the slider to exactly the same position? 5. Can you link to a datasheet for the pot?

Comment: 5. Are you sure that your VCC is always the same 6. Suppose you would measure the voltage multiple times with a voltmeter (a very good one) at the wiper contact of the potmeter. Then "obviously" if your voltmeter has enough digits (high resolution like it can measure: 1.23456789 V exactly) then the reading would **NEVER** be always the same. That's because there is always some noise. So the voltage does change (slightly) all the time. And voltmeters and ADCs vary over time (drift). Your readouts change, that is to be expected. But they should not change too much.

Comment: yes my vcc is always same. and as you say voltage not change too much  but resistance is change all time. i edit my post also.

Comment: But if your pot is connected to VCC and GND, are you measuring resistance, or voltage? If measuring resistance, with what and how are you measuring it? I am quite sure you can't measure pot resistance with a multimeter while it is connected into a circuit, it must be disconnected from a circuit.

Comment: 7. Are you measuring resistance with the power on? (You can't.) You would need to disconnect at least two of the pot pins before measuring resistance. 8. Your error is +/- 1.5%. On an 80 mm slider that means +/- 1.2 mm. Try sticking a block of something onto the pot to act as a mechanical stop and then check for repeatability. That will give you an exact stop which would be better than your pen mark.

Comment: As @Transistor says, use a hard stop. But even if you use a pen mark, always approach from the same direction in the same way.  Backlash due to mechanical slop can make quite a difference, as can changes in the viewing angle depending on the shape of the housing

Comment: Here some misunderstanding , what i do at some point i measure the voltage with multimeter and after disconnect power supply i measure the resistance of port.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the problem is caused by a faulty potentiometer with bad / loose contacts or terminations.

Potentiometer replacement would confirm that.

Comment: i have same type of more slider potentiometer but in all potentiometer have same problem.

Comment: Have you checked the potentiometers alone or in-circuit?

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note:

1. You can't measure the pot resistance with the circuit powered up. The pot voltage will upset the voltage applied by the test meter.
2. If the pot supply voltage is constant you *can* measure the voltage between wiper and ground and use that and the measured total resistance to calculate the effective resistance.
3. If you want to measure using a resistance meter you really need to disconnect at least two of the pot's pins from the circuit to isolate it from the circuit during measurement.
4. You didn't specify which pot you're using but the longest is 60 mm so your ±1.5 kΩ on a 100 kΩ pot is ±0.9 mm which would be hard to achieve when lining up with a pen mark. Use a hard stop instead.

[image]

*Figure 1. The linear taper resistance curve.*

5. As you can see from the plot the pot is fairly crude regarding its linearity. 80% of the resistance change (10% to 90%) will be on 46% (30% to 76%) of it's "rotation".

Comment: we use the 10k with 20% tolerance and travel 30 mm.

Comment: So your +/-1.5% error corresponds to 0.45 mm repeatability on positioning the slider relative to your pen mark. Do you think you can achieve that repeatability without a stop block?